# GCP Deployment Manager third party resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

Just wanted to make sure my understanding is correct. Based on my research, Deployment Manager can integrate with third party APIs, although is a BETA feature at this moment.

So my question is, can Deployment Manager automate Google resources and also external resources(e.g. on premises resource using third party API)?

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/type-providers/creating-type-provider

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/type-providers/process-adding-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely but after you successfully register the third party API as a **type provider** (not manage by Google).

Take into account:

1. your API is map to http methods

```yaml
get htttp://onpremises.com/api/yourresource
delete htttp://onpremises.com/api/yourresource
put htttp://onpremises.com/api/yourresource
post htttp://onpremises.com/api/yourresource
```

2. API's descriptor document, something like [this](https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/compute/beta/rest)
3. your **config.yaml**

```yaml
resources:
- name: my-api
  type: project/your-api:yourresource
  properties:
  - name: Jane
    website: onpremises.com/api
```

**This will cause a http post request to be made by the deployment-manager to your API.**